# ttk.Separator appearing as dot "." when using .pack() layout manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, separator, ttk

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924785/ttk-separator-set-the-length-width), but I'm using the layout manager `pack` rather than `grid` so the answer in the alternate thread doesn't work for me.

Code:

```
    iconLabelImage = ttk.Label(labelFrame)
    self.iconImage = PhotoImage(file='images\icon.png')
    iconLabelImage['image'] = self.iconImage
    iconLabelImage.pack(anchor='w')   

    sep = ttk.Separator(parameterFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
    sep.pack(side="right", fill="y")
```

The `LabelFrame` is a child of the `parameterFrame`.

It doesn't matter what parameters I change I can't seem to get the separator to extend more than a pixel even though it exists in a larger frame.

Any ideas?

Comment: add `expand=True`

Comment: first step should always be to read the documentation. `pack` has several options for defining how a widget fills the space given to it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the idea is same with the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924785/ttk-separator-set-the-length-width) you have provided above. That means:

> The expand option tells the manager to assign additional space to the widget box. If the parent widget is made larger than necessary to hold all packed widgets, any exceeding space will be distributed among all widgets that have the expand option set to a non-zero value.
>   -[effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)

The point here you should focus on is: **non-zero value/weight**.
So to solve this problem using `pack` method add `expand=True` option.

Comment: I tried this additional parameter before posting the question. It doesn't change the line's length :(

Comment: Isn't this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want but its not working on mine.  Can you post your code to double check that I'm not missing something?

Comment: Ah, maybe the reason is that you have put `ttk.Separator` in a `Frame` widget (as a container)...

Comment: Yes, I think the reason is that. I'm so confident because of this LoC: `sep = ttk.Separator(parameterFrame, orient=VERTICAL)`

Comment: So a separator can't be in a frame?  What is its parent then?

Comment: [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack-method) says: "Expand specifies whether the widgets should be expanded to fill any extra space in the geometry master. If false (default), the widget is not expanded." If you're using a `Frame` widget, that means there will be no extra space to fill. I think you have noticed that I frequently quote from http://effbot.org. You (actually me too) should read, read and read. As you can see in my [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TbFL1kVz) code that I've assigned the root window as the parent of the separator.

Comment: By saying "If you're using a `Frame` widget, that means there will be no extra space to fill." I mean if the parent is a `Frame` widget, it's not possible to expand because there's no extra space. Simply: expand works when there's any extra space to fill. `Root` is just like an open plain: if you put widgets randomly on it, they can be placed far from one another. If you put them in a container, they will fit into it. You need to make the container larger in order to use `expand` option for the widgets in it, otherwise by default, it's not large enough to do that.

Comment: So I tried using the root window as the parent and with no luck. In fact the root has a ttk.notebook child which has its own parameterFrame child in the first tab. I wanted to put the separator between elements on the parameterFrame. Maybe the problem is trying to put the separators in the tab of a notebook.

Comment: You're welcome! And yes, it doesn't really have to be a `Frame` at all -- in fact, there are other container widgets as well e.g. `LabelFrame`, `Toplevel` etc. And in this case, seems like `ttk.Notebook` (another example to container widgets) behaves as the container for the separator (and maybe for others as well).

Comment: to clarify, you absolutely _can_ put separators in a frame. The problem seems to be that your separator is in a _small_ frame, and the problem isn't that the separator won't grow, it's that the frame isn't set up to grow. If you had created an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we could do a better job answering your question.