# increasing width python seperator using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been working on a project where I use Separators and I've just can't find out how I make them thicker!
this is the code for it I've got at the moment:

```
tkinter.ttk.Separator(master, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=1, row=1, rowspan=4, sticky='ns')
```

so how do I make the Separator thicker/wider?
ps. The code is only a small part of my project

Comment: Have you tried to use padding?

Comment: I think that's not possible, but I may be wrong

Comment: I believe `ttk.Separator` ignores any attempts at styling it except to change the color. It's kind of the point of `ttk` (as a Tcl/Tk Tile extension) that you give up a lot of control over your widgets in exchange for them looking consistent and reasonably "native".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ttk.Separator set the length/width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924785/ttk-separator-set-the-length-width)

Comment: You could also use a frame and label to create a wide spacer and I imagine you could also use `canvas()` to draw a custom spacer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ttk separator widget isn't designed to be modified in that way. Part of the point of the themed (ttk) widgets is that they adhere to a common theme and thus can't be customized.

You can use a an empty frame widget, which allows you to set the width, height, border style, color, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it apparently goes against the "theme" of tkinter, as pointed out by Bryan, I wanted to do this too.

The solution I found is simply stack multiple separators. If you're using grid geometry manager, you'll need to provide extra rows or columns to fit as many separators as necessary. For me, three separators did the trick, and aesthetically, I didn't find it offensive in any way:

```
ttk.Separator(master=root,orient='vertical').grid(row=0,column=11,rowspan=2,sticky='ns')
ttk.Separator(master=root,orient='vertical').grid(row=0,column=12,rowspan=2,sticky='ns')
ttk.Separator(master=root,orient='vertical').grid(row=0,column=13,rowspan=2,sticky='ns')
```

But as Bryan suggests, you can use an empty Frame widget. Example code for that can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68179426/7759839