# Tkinter Set Thickness of Separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I am using ttk's `Separator` objects to create horizontal dividers in my application.

```py
separator = ttk.Separator(frame, orient='horizontal')
separator.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=10)
```

However, every separator is the same thickness/weight - about 2-3 pixels.

Is it possible to create a thicker separator?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `Frame` instead of `Separator`.

Comment: @acw1668 How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Manby Try using: `separator = tk.Frame(frame, bd=0, height=<thickness>)`

Comment: Acw and @TheLizzard, thank you both for your help, I have now answered this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been made aware that a `Frame` is a good option here instead of a `Separator`.

I created a frame with the following code:

```py
separator2 = tk.Frame(frame, bd=10, relief='sunken', height=4)
separator2.pack(side='top', fill='x')
```

Here is a comparison between a ttk `Separator` and my `Frame`:
[image]

Thanks to acw1668 and TheLizzard for the comments which suggested this.

Comment: Just a note: you can add a `background` parameter inside the `tk.Frame(...)` to change the colour the separator.